# TeXstudio Citation Help

Tags: biblatex, citing, texstudio, ieeetran, sharelatex

I am having trouble getting TeXstudio to produce IEEE style citations.  I am using biblatex.  When I compile the document, the citations are referenced by their ID, not by a number in brackets like IEEE should have.  Below is a sample of text from my document.  The bold face text is supposed to be [1] and [2], but instead is showing up as the ID field from my bibliography file.  In ShareLatex, the document works properly.

Sample Text: 
"The dual extruder tool head was purchased from Lulzbot as a "Flexy Dually",
since one of the dual extruders was the "Flexistruder" **Flexy1**. The
"Flexistruder" is designed to feed flexible filaments like "NinjaFLEX" (a thermoplastic
polyurathane, TPU **NinjaFlex1**)."

Code:

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{easylist}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

In text, I used the "\cite{Flexy1}" command.

Bibliography:

```
@misc{Flexy1, 
    title={LulzBot TAZ FlexyDually Tool Head v1}, url={https://www.lulzbot.com/support/lulzbot-taz-flexydually-tool-head-v1-0}, 
    journal={LulzBot TAZ FlexyDually Tool Head v1}, publisher={Lulzbot.com},
    note={Accessed 06-09-2016}
}
@misc{NinjaFlex1,
    title={NinjaFlex® Flexible 3D Printing Filament}, url={http://ninjatek.com/products/ninjaflex-filaments/}, journal={NinjaTek}, 
    publisher={NinjaTek Products},
    note={Accessed 06-09-2016}
    }
```

I would really like to get the citations to show up as IEEE style, and would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you actually run biber? Or instruct texstudio to use biber?

Comment: The symptoms seem to suggest you did not run Biber or the Biber run failed for some reason. Check out [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). If your editor is set up correctly you still need to call Biber, only then will you get to see the citations. (You might want to have a look at the `.blg` file after you have run Biber.)